# Bayesian estimation for the exponential distribution under the Bregman divergence distance

Tags: bayesian, exponential-distribution

Suppose, I have a random variable $X$ that follows a negative exponential distribution
$$
f(x;\theta)=\theta e^{-\theta x};~~x\in(0,\infty), \theta>0
$$
Then my question is, what will be Bayes estimate of $\theta$ under the Bregman divergence distance.